# How can I use a custom TabItem control when databinding a TabControl in WPF?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, user-interface, styles, itemtemplate

I have a custom control that is derived from `TabItem`, and I want to databind that custom `TabItem` to a stock `TabControl`. I would rather avoid creating a new `TabControl` just for this rare case.

This is what I have and I'm not having any luck getting the correct control to be loaded. In this case I want to use my `ClosableTabItem` control instead of the stock `TabItem` control.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabCases" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
            Controls:ClosableTabItem.TabClose="TabClosed" >
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Controls:ClosableTabItem}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Entities:Case}">
            <CallLog:CaseReadOnlyDisplay DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**EDIT:** This is what I ended up with, rather than trying to bind a custom control.
The "[CloseCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935043/how-can-i-get-a-close-button-on-a-templated-tabitem-in-wpf)" im getting from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935043/how-can-i-get-a-close-button-on-a-templated-tabitem-in-wpf).

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            Background="LightGray"
                            BorderBrush="Black" 
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            CornerRadius="25,0,0,0"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              Margin="20,1,5,1"/>
                            <Button 
                                Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
                                Cursor="Hand"
                                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                Focusable="False"
                                Margin="1,1,5,1"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                BorderThickness="0">
                                <Image Source="/Russound.Windows;component/Resources/Delete.png" Height="10" />
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />                            
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkBlue" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to set the `DataType` of the `DataTemplate` in this case. The value of the `ItemTemplate` property is used whenever a new item needs to be added, and in the case of a tab control it will be used to create a new `TabItem`. You should declare an instance of your class within the `DataTemplate` itself:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabCases" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Controls:ClosableTabItem.TabClose="TabClosed">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Controls:ClosableTabItem>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
            </Controls:ClosableTabItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Entities:Case}">
            <CallLog:CaseReadOnlyDisplay DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

This will cause a new `ClosableTabItem` to be created whenever a new tab is added to the `TabControl`.

**Update**; From your comment, it sounds like that the `ItemTemplate` controls what is created within the `TabItem`, rather than changing the `TabItem` itself. To do what you want to do, but for a `TreeView`, you would set the `HeaderTemplate`. Unfortunately, I don't see a `HeaderTemplate` property of `TabControl`.

I did some searching, and [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out) modifies the contents of the tab headers by adding controls to `TabItem.Header`. Maybe you could create a `Style` for your `TabItems` that would add the close button that your class is currently adding?

Comment: I have tried that, and what seems to happen is that my custom control is loaded inside of a stock TabItem. This leaves me with a border around my custom control, as well as my custom control doesn't know how to pass focus through to the stock tabitem.

Answer (score 7):

found a way,
derive a class from TabControl and override this function, in my case I want the items of the tab control (when bound) to be CloseableTabItems

```
public class CloseableTabControl : TabControl
    {
        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            return new CloseableTabItem();
        }
    }
```

HTH Someone

Sam